# How to compose two lambdas of type "delegate" in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda

Lets assume we have defined two Lambdas.

```
Func<TInput, TOutput> a = …;
Func<TInput1, TInput2, TOutput> b = …;
```

Now lets assume that we have some code that does not work with generics and receives these Lambdas as not further typed delegates.

```
delegate da = a;
delegate db = b;
```

In that code, we want to compose the two lambdas / delegates to a new, composed lambda e.g. `(i1, i2) => b(a(i1), i2)`, but a and b are not accessible, only da and db are accessible. How can this be done in an elegant way?

Comment: Do you mean `Delegate`, i.e. `System.Delegate`? Why don't you just `DynamicInvoke`?

Comment: I mean `System.Delegate`. I do not want to Invoke it, I want to pass on the composed delegate.

Comment: I meant `(i1, i2) => b(a(i1), i2)` should turn into something like `(i1, i2) => db.DynamicInvoke(da.DynamicInvoke(i1), i2)`, but i see Vera rind has already covered that in her answer below. When you have the strong type, like in `a`, you can say `a(i1)` (the same as `a.Invoke(i1)`) because the signature is known at compile-time. When you only have `System.Delegate`, you need `da.DynamicInvkoe(i1)` instead. It cannot be checked at compile-time if the parameter count (and types) is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this what you want?:

```
Func<int, int> a = p0 => p0 << 1;
Func<int, int, int> b = (p0, p1) => p0 + p1;

Delegate da = a;
Delegate db = b;

var inner = da.Method.GetParameters().Length < db.Method.GetParameters().Length ? da : db;
var outer = inner == da ? db : da;

Func<int, int, int> c = (i1, i2) => (int)outer.DynamicInvoke(inner.DynamicInvoke(i1), i2);
```

I would prefer to create an expression tree to build a new lambda that's created as you want. Maybe there is more logic needed to determine which argument should be passed to `a` and at which parameter the result of `a` is passed to `b`.

Is that the way you want to go?

Comment: I currently have a solution with an Expression tree, but your solution is a good/better answer for my question here. Thanks, I will see which of the two two Solutions I will use due to some other considerations.